# Can I start the outcome of System.out.print from right?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to give a number as a binary number in java. To solve this problem I would have to start the outcome of system.out.print from right an not from left.

System.out.print("1")
System.out.print("0")

10

but it should look like this;

System.out.print("1")
System.out.print("0")

01

---

```
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    
    if (t<0)
        System.out.println("0");
    
    
    else if (t >= 0)
    {
        while(t != 0)
        {
            if (t%2==1)
                System.out.print("1");
            else if (t%2==0)
                System.out.print("0");
            
            t = t/2;
```

Comment: You'll need to build up a String as you go, then print it.

Comment: use stringbuilder

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this issue than what you have asked for would be to use a `StringBuilder`, and `append` the characters to the `StringBuilder` as you evaluate them.

Then when you're ready to print them all out, call `reverse()` on the `StringBuilder` before passing it to `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Thank you but easier would be System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1));

Comment: Sure, but your question was how to print a string from right to left.